# Regex to delete js HTML attributes

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I've got this file from google that has these `js` attributes like `jsname="data", jscontroller="data"` etc.

I'd like to use Atom's find and replace with regex feature to replace all attributes beginning with `js*="*"` with blanks.

How would the regex for this be?

So `<div class="l-o-c-qd" jsname="name" jscontroller="somecontroller">Text</div>`

will be `<div class="l-o-c-qd">Text</div>`

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "we'll do your work for you for free" site.
Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with

Comment: You might use: /[ ]js\w*=\"[^\"]+\"/g and replace with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Search correct RegEx corresponding to js*="*" en replace it with nothing (check space before/after for avoid double spaces after replacement)